# Не получается принять массив

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, пересмотрел кучу статей, но ответа не нашел

Мне отправляются данные на скрипт, все значения получается сохранить, кроме значений с массива.

Сохраняю так

```
$summa =  $_POST['sum'];
$product =  $_POST['order_num'];
$nazvanie = $_POST['products'];
```

Значения суммы и продукта сохраняет. А вместо название записывается - "array"

Пробовал так:

```
    $nazvanie = $_POST['products']['name'];
```

В таком случае вообще ничего не сохраняет.

Пример входящих данных:

```
{"date":"2022- 
08","order_id":"5338283","order_num":"test","sum":"1000.00","currency":"rub","products": 
[{"name":"test","price":"1000.00","quantity":"1","sum":"1000.00"}]}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается принять массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441073/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Comment: Достаточно переести массив на фронте в JSON, затем на бэея его пинять и перекодировать в массив

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому что $_POST["products"] содержит массив. Из кода не понятно, как ты его выводишь. Попробуй это для вывода первого элемента массива:

```
$nazvanie = $_POST["products"];
print_r($nazvanie[0])
```